# How to define property at runtime in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following property defined for my database access in nodejs. The problem is that I need also the url parameter defined for a certain function. I have therefore written the helper function `getDataUrl()`

```
var config = {
    db: {
        db: 'dbname', // the name of the database
        host: "12.12.12.12", // the ip adress of the database
        port: 10091, // the port of the mongo db
        username: "name", //the username if not needed use undefined
        password: "pw", // the password for the db access
        url:  undefined // also tried url: getDataUrl()
     }

};

function getDataUrl() {
       var dataUrl = "mongodb://";
       if (config.db.username !== undefined) {
           dataUrl += config.db.username + ':' + config.db.password + '@';
       }
       dataUrl += config.db.host + ":" + config.db.port;
       dataUrl += '/' + config.db.db
       return dataUrl;
}

module.exports = config;
```

However I do not want to call this function but use instead the property `config.db.url`.

I am at the moment struggling how to do that. I have tried the following:

1. write `url: getDataUrl()` this produce: TypeError: Cannot read property 'db' of undefined
2. call `getDataUrl()` which then writes the property, however this does not overwrite the url property. When I then read the value the following error occures: `Cannot read property 'url' of undefined`
3. write `config.db.url = getDataUrl();` this also does not overwrite the url property.

I am very new to JavaScript and nodejs therefore I do not know how to achieve this behavior or if it is even possible.

Comment: What do you mean by "this does not overwrite the url property" in #2 and #3, how do you see that result? It should work.

Comment: but not when I read the values, I assume that has something to do with asynchronous calls or not? I have made an update.

Comment: As @MartinLinux observed, you've use `configs` instead of `config` in the function. Fix that typo and #2 and #3 will work. And use strict mode so it throws meaningful exceptions on undeclared variables!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a [getter property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters):

```
var config = {
    db: {
        db: 'dbname', // the name of the database
        host: "12.12.12.12", // the ip adress of the database
        port: 10091, // the port of the mongo db
        username: "name", //the username if not needed use undefined
        password: "pw", // the password for the db access
        get url() {
            var dataUrl = "mongodb://";
            if (this.username)
                dataUrl += this.username + ':' + this.password + '@';
            dataUrl += this.host + ":" + this.port + '/' + this.db;
            return dataUrl;
        }
    }
};
console.log(config.db.url); // automatically computed on [every!] access
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix

> write url: getDataUrl() this produce: TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'db' of undefined

you should change the "configs" variable to "config" in your getDataUrl() function:

```
function getDataUrl() {
       var dataUrl = "mongodb://";
       if (config.db.username !== undefined) {
           dataUrl += config.db.username + ':' + config.db.password + '@';
       }
       dataUrl += config.db.host + ":" + config.db.port;
       dataUrl += '/' + config.db.db
       return dataUrl;
}
```

Comment: Sorry this was a typo in the question, I have updated the question.